# Extract the title of a YouTube video Python

Tags: python, youtube, extract, screen-scraping, youtube-dl

I have written a small piece of code in python to extract the audio from a YouTube video. Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

link = input("Enter the video link:")
name = input("Enter the title of the video:")

path = f'D:\\{name}.mp3'

ydl_opts = {
    'outtmpl':path,
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([link])
```

What I wanted to do here is to get the title of the video by using the link instead of asking the user for the title of the video. I tried out few methods, but they didn't work out for me. Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extract_info method in folowing way:

```
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    info_dict = ydl.extract_info(video, download=False)
    video_title = info_dict.get('title', None)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Would you mind helping me out with another issue? If yes, then here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63918414/youtube-dl-python-details-of-extracted-audio-file-are-not-displayed