# YouTube-DL Python details of extracted audio file are not displayed

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube, extract, youtube-dl

I have written a small piece of code in python to extract the audio from a YouTube video. Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

link = input("Enter the video link:")

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    info_dict = ydl.extract_info(link, download=False)
    video_title = info_dict.get('title', None)

path = f'D:\\{video_title}.mp3'

ydl_opts.update({'outtmpl':path})

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([link])
```

This is the folder where the output audio file is saved:
[image: Output File Folder]

As you can see, all the details of the audio file are displayed, such as Date Modified, Type and Size.

However, if I change `path = f'D:\\{video_title}.mp3'` to `path = f'D:\\YT_Files\\{video_title}.mp3'`, then the file details are not getting displayed.
[image: Output File Folder]

Any idea about why this is so? Is there any way to solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since YT_Files is a directory, you could set the path as `path = f'D:\\{video_title}.mp3'` which causes metadata to be displayed. Then try to move the file to YT_Files using `os.system()`. Then you should have metadata on YT_Folders. If not then its fault of Windows explorer i assume. Following code should work but i am not 100% sure this syntax will work on windows.

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

link = input("Enter the video link:")

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    info_dict = ydl.extract_info(link, download=False)
    video_title = info_dict.get('title', None)

path = f'D:\\{video_title}.mp3'

ydl_opts.update({'outtmpl':path})

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([link])
import os
os.system('move D:\\*.mp3 D:\\YT_Files\\')
```

Run this code and check if metadata is there or not. Dont check by windows explorer. Go to “Properties”. Click on the “Details” tab and scroll down.
If you find the properties with `Date-Modified` or `Type` then the problem is in Windows Explorer/File Explorer but if you dont then i will try to debug

Comment: Tried it...Still not working:(  Do you know any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Ok do this download the file in `D:\ ` not `D:\YT_Files` and see if the metadata is there, then copy the file into `YT_Files`, does metadata gets removed or is still there in `YT_Files` @Sushil

Comment: If I manually copy paste the file, then the metadata is there. But if I do it through Python, it is not there.

Comment: Did you run my code exactly as i given above? Also check my updated post

Comment: Yes. I did not change anything.

Comment: Did you check the properties of mp3 with metadata and mp3 with no metadata. Did you find any differnece

Comment: I think that I have figured out the problem. It was the folder name that caused the chaos. When I saved the audio file in YT_Files, the metadata wasn't displayed. But when I saved the audio in a folder called YTFiles, the metadata was displayed. Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: Ohh...Sorry. I was wrong! After further testing, I discovered that the file name wasn't the problem. The main problem was the folder not being open. When I kept the folder where I want to save the audio file open and ran my code, the metadata was displayed. But when I kept it closed and ran my code, the metadata wasn't displayed.

Comment: Good, sometimes researching more about question prevents asking in stakoverflw